# Retrieve number of rows in Google Sheets

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, row

I need a JavaScript method for my webpage to count how many rows are in a Google sheet (it's used as a response sheet for a form). I've been scouring the web for easy tutorials on how to make Google Sheets into a database.

Is there a simpler way to do it?

I don't have much experience in Google scripts, but all I need is a way I can have read access to the spreadsheet using preferably Ajax or some similar JavaScript method.

Answer (score 5):

To retrieve the number of rows in your Google Spreadsheet use the following:

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1qNCf0wKl................");
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("sheet_name");
var number = sheet.getMaxRows().toString();
var number = number.replace(".0","");
Logger.log(number);
```

In order to have read access to a Spreadsheet the guidance provided in the following link is good enough:

[Query Google Spreadsheet with URL Parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22695365/query-google-spreadsheet-with-url-parameters)

For example, if you want to get all the cells with the word «budget» in your Spreadsheet, use the following script:

```
var id = "1qNCf0wKlx1RF......";
var column = "A";
var query = "budget";
var url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/"+id+"/gviz/tq?tq=SELECT%20*%20where%20"+column+"%20contains%20%22"+query+"%22";
var text = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText().toString();
Logger.log(text);
```

For this, the Spreadsheet has to be published previously. After retrieving the «budget» rows the text has to be formated, but that's another issue.

Comment: this is only good for the total rows, empty or not

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you can do

Write a simple Apps script using [ContentService](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/content#serving_json_from_scripts) that will return a JSON with the number of rows in the spreadsheet (and any other info you need). To get the number of rows, you can use the [getLastRow()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getLastRow%28%29) function

Publish your script as a service(web app) and make an AJAX call from your JS code.