# How to count number of rows in Google Sheets?

Tags: php, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

Actually I want to add a new row after last very row and sometimes there are a couple of empty rows at the end so in this case, I will have to update the empty row with new data after the last row (which is not empty). So in this case either I have to reach very last row having data dynamically or get the total number of rows and then loop back to the rows which are having data so that I will be able to add new record at right place.

My so far code is:

```
$worksheets = $spreadsheet->getWorksheetFeed()->getEntries();
       $worksheet = $worksheets[1];
       $cellFeed = $worksheet->getCellFeed();
       $counter = 0;
       for($i=1;$i<=2;$i++)
       {
         for($j=1;$j<=3;$j++)
          {
            $topLeftCornerCell = $cellFeed->getCell($i, $j);// $i = rows and $j = columns
            echo $topLeftCornerCell->getcontent(); // "last_name"
          }
          $counter++;


        }
```

In this code I am simply fetching record with two rows and three columns.

Is there any method for row count in Google Sheets for PHP?

Comment: Are you using the Sheets REST API? It has methods to append rows / data.

Comment: @tehhowch Google Api

Comment: As I said, Sheets v4 has methods which do what you want. https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#AppendCellsRequest

Comment: @tehhowch I am following this tutorial https://www.twilio.com/blog/2017/03/google-spreadsheets-and-php.html Can you help me regarding this piece of code

Comment: That looks like an outdated tutorial - the client library it uses only implements v3 of the Sheets API. I have no interest in learning how to use an outdated client library for a legacy API version. Switch to Sheets v4 and a real client library - Google provides one for PHP, along with examples and documentation.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Retrieve number of rows in Google Sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20848496/retrieve-number-of-rows-in-google-sheets)

Answer (score 1):

A simple formula to get the number of rows in a worksheet would be:

```
=COUNTA(A:A) + COUNTBLANK(A:A)
```

The first part counts all the cells with values in column A and the second part counts all the cells without values in column A. Add that together and you get the total number of cells in the column, which is the total number of rows in the worksheet.

And of course it's dynamic, so as rows are deleted or added, that number will keep giving you the correct row count.

Change each `A:A` to `1:1` to get the column count:

```
=COUNTA(1:1) + COUNTBLANK(1:1)
```

If it's possible for you to have that calculate in a cell in the spreadsheet, you should then be able to extract it using PHP.